# Want to create a common method inside map function in react

Tags: javascript

Below is my code

```
const newState = permissionData.map(obj => {
      if (obj.component.includes('Client')) {
        if ((permissionName.includes('Client')) && (name.includes('create'))) {
          return { ...obj, createPermission: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 };
        }
        if ((permissionName.includes('Client')) && (name.includes('view'))) {
          return { ...obj, viewPermission: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 };
        }
        if ((permissionName.includes('Client')) && (name.includes('delete'))) {
          return { ...obj, deletePermission: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 };
        }
        if ((permissionName.includes('Client')) && (name.includes('update'))) {
          return { ...obj, updatePermission: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 };
        }
      }

      if (obj.component.includes('Project')) {
        if ((permissionName.includes('Project')) && (name.includes('create'))) {
          return { ...obj, createPermission: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 };
        }
        if ((permissionName.includes('Project')) && (name.includes('view'))) {
          return { ...obj, viewPermission: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 };
        }
        if ((permissionName.includes('Project')) && (name.includes('delete'))) {
          return { ...obj, deletePermission: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 };
        }
        if ((permissionName.includes('Project')) && (name.includes('update'))) {
          return { ...obj, updatePermission: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 };
        }
      }

      if (obj.component.includes('Schema')) {
        if ((permissionName.includes('Schema')) && (name.includes('create'))) {
          return { ...obj, createPermission: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 };
        }
        if ((permissionName.includes('Schema')) && (name.includes('view'))) {
          return { ...obj, viewPermission: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 };
        }
        if ((permissionName.includes('Schema')) && (name.includes('delete'))) {
          return { ...obj, deletePermission: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 };
        }
        if ((permissionName.includes('Schema')) && (name.includes('update'))) {
          return { ...obj, updatePermission: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 };
        }
      }

      if (obj.component.includes('Dataset')) {
        if ((permissionName.includes('Dataset')) && (name.includes('create'))) {
          return { ...obj, createPermission: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 };
        }
        if ((permissionName.includes('Dataset')) && (name.includes('view'))) {
          return { ...obj, viewPermission: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 };
        }
        if ((permissionName.includes('Dataset')) && (name.includes('delete'))) {
          return { ...obj, deletePermission: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 };
        }
        if ((permissionName.includes('Dataset')) && (name.includes('update'))) {
          return { ...obj, updatePermission: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 };
        }
      }
      return obj;
    });
```

Above code is working well, however since the code is repetitive I want to make a common method to optimize the code.

But not sure how can I do it.

I am trying something like this -

```
const checkPermission = (obj: object, type: string, permissionName: string, name: string, checked: boolean) => {
  if (obj.component.includes(type)) {
    if ((permissionName.includes(type)) && (name.includes('create'))) {
      return { ...obj, createPermission: checked };
    }
    if ((permissionName.includes(type)) && (name.includes('view'))) {
      return { ...obj, viewPermission: checked };
    }
    if ((permissionName.includes(type)) && (name.includes('delete'))) {
      return { ...obj, deletePermission: checked };
    }
    if ((permissionName.includes(type)) && (name.includes('update'))) {
      return { ...obj, updatePermission: checked };
    }
  }
};
```

And I am calling this method like this -

checkPermission(obj, 'Client', permissionName, name, event.target.checked);

But it's not working. Any pointers/ideas as how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `['Client', 'Project', 'Schema', 'Dataset']` strings are all used identically, so put them into an array and `.find` the one that matches the `.includes` conditions, removing one dimension of repetitiveness.

After that, the proper action can be found by similarly iterating over an array of `['create', 'view', 'delete', 'update']`. With that, you can update the property on the state object with bracket notation.

```
const newState = permissionData.map(obj => {
    const entity = ['Client', 'Project', 'Schema', 'Dataset'].find(str => obj.component.includes(str));
    if (!entity || !permissionName.includes(entity)) {
        return obj;
    }
    const action = ['create', 'view', 'delete', 'update'].find(a => name.includes(a));
    return action
        ? { ...obj, [action + 'Permission']: event.target.checked ? 1 : 0 }
        : obj;
});
```

If possible, you might consider a better state structure - instead of having, for example

```
{
  createPermission: 1
  // other possible Permission keys
}
```

If the object doesn't contain any keys *other* than Permission keys, the `Permission` suffix doesn't add any useful information - rename the state array variable name to include `Permission`, and then you no longer have to use the ugly lookup with bracket notation.

If the object *can* contain non-Permission keys, then consider changing it so that `Permission` is a sub-property. And if the Permission values can only be 0 or 1, it might be more appropriate to use booleans.

```
{
  // state properties...

  // and also
  permissions: {
    create: true
    // etc
  }
}
```

Or have an array of enabled permissions.

```
permissions: ['create']
```

Or, if only one is possible, a single string.

```
permissions: 'create'
```